# Same Rabbi (Posek) for husband and wife

Tags: halacha, halacha-theory, marriage, posek-psak-decisor-ruling

Do a husband and a wife need to have the same Rabbi (Posek) or can they have their own Rabbis?

Comment: Why might you think they would or wouldn't need to? What research have you done already? Please [edit] to elaborate. While your at it, consider adding any tags that might be relevant to the question (perhaps something about poskim or marriage would be appropriate).

Comment: @DoubleAA I guess for shalom bait and, her to accept her husbands minhagim...

Comment: @sam I have heard and been taught that they each have their own (plus usually a "marriage rov" and/or a rov to answer tahara questions). I found this surprising until I realized how useful it could be in times of disagreement.

Answer (score 2):

Rabbi Hershel Schachter has an mp3 on yutorah.org on "Kitchen Kashrus" where he says that they could each follow their own rabbi on something like opening bottles on shabbos.

For matters of communal customs, e.g. how many hours to wait after meat before milk, or whether to eat *kitniyos*, they should belong to a single community; assuming he had a strong communal background, that's usually his. (Rabbi Schachter states that if the wife has a strong communal background and the husband is new to observant Judaism, he should join her community.)

I'll just add that practically, for "family purity" matters that affect both of them, they kind of need to figure out who they'll follow.